# finding speed given acceleration and displacement but without velocity and time

Tags: physics

Your task is to correctly answer the following question: Assuming the spinner starts from rest, what will its speed be (in cm/s)    after travelling 250 cm?
the acceleration is 1.57cm/s/s but how are you supposed to solve this without velocity and time using algebra?

Comment: you better ask Firmino :D

Answer (score 0):

Using kinematics:
$$v_f^2=v_i^2+2ad$$

$$v_f=\sqrt{(1.57)(2)(250)}$$

$$v_f=28 \,cm/s$$